# Is this sentence correct? How to parse it?

Tags: sentence-construction

**"Even a small bird has many more bones in its neck than in a tall giraffe. "**

The sentence structure is quite weird, how to parse it?

Comment: Dump the second "in" - no bird has bones in a giraffe...

Comment: @Stephie Interesting, I didn't even notice the second **in**...

Answer (score 1):

The result is "A giraffe has very few bones in its neck".
That said, the sentence could be simplified (but changes its sense) :

> Even a bird has more bones than a giraffe

you add **small** to talk about the bird

you add **many** to enhance the difference (**more bones** means giraffe has 10 bones, and bird has 12, but **many more** will be a difference of 10 to 50)

you add **in its neck** to talk about the number of bones into the neck of each animal

you add **tall** to enhance the surprise about the fact that a giraffe has a tall neck, and so should have more bones

It finally makes **Even a small bird has many more bones in its neck than a tall giraffe**

The 2nd **in** of the initial answer is wrong, since it would mean that a bird has bones in a giraffe, but fewer than in bird's neck, which is non sense, a bird doesn't have any bones in a giraffe...

Answer (score 1):

> "Even a small bird has many more bones in its neck than in a tall
>   giraffe. "

That sentence sounds weird because it mixes up (combines) two different but related patterns:

**There are many more bones *in the neck of a small bird* than *in the neck of a tall giraffe*.**

**A small bird has more bones in its neck than a tall giraffe has (in its neck).**

In the first pattern, with "there are", the prepositional phrases "in the neck of a small bird" and "in the neck of a tall giraffe" are juxtaposed on either side of "than".

In the second pattern, the subject-verb phrases "a small bird has..." and "a tall giraffe has..." are juxtaposed on either side of "than".